# Raspberry Pi PXE-boot fails despite response from router

Tags: networking, boot, dhcp

I'm trying to set up a network with raspberry-pi's which use PXE to boot. The networks router, another raspberry-pi, is configured to use 10.0.0.1/24 as the interfaces address. To configure ip-addresses for the network-participants I use dnsmasq. All of this is part of a tutorial I found in a magazine, the only thing I do different is the network. Instead of using an existing network I created a new one, with a switch, some cables and dnsmasq responsible for DHCP.
My dnsmasq-config is

```
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.111,12h
interface=eth0
log-dhcp
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/my/tftpboot/location
pxe-service=0,"Raspberry Pi Boot"
tftp-unique-root
dhcp-host=b8:27:eb:XX:XX:XX,10.0.0.10
```

(There surely are some things in that config that can be done better, but first and foremost I want a working config)
When powering up a raspberry-pi with an OS from a sd-card the dhcp-lease works as expected. A request is sent and dnsmasq answers. This is a snippet of the output of `tshark -i eth0`:

```
4   0.870291      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 385 DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0xd2b85d76
5   0.899177     10.0.0.1 -> 10.0.0.10    DHCP 347 DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0xd2b85d76
```

When booting the pi without OS, therefore forcing PXE (and yes, the pi is configured to use PXE), a DHCPDISCOVER-packet is sent instead of a DHCPREQUEST. dnsmasq does not answer the DHCPDISCOVER with a DHCPOFFER, which halts the whole PXE-process. Running `tshark -i eth0` again gives me:

```
10 576.846990      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 376 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xa4804676
11 640.339356      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 376 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xa4804676
12 705.054463      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 376 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xa4804676
13 768.191770      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 376 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xa4804676
14 832.952547      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 376 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xa4804676
15 896.334800      0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 DHCP 376 DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0xa4804676
```

This goes on for some time.

**UPDATE:** This is the log of dnsmasq, queried with `grep dnsmasq /var/log/syslog`

```
[...]
Jan 25 11:15:37 host dnsmasq[4958]: using nameserver 192.168.178.1#53
Jan 25 11:15:37 host dnsmasq[4958]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
Jan 25 11:15:37 host systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jan 25 11:44:06 host systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Jan 25 11:44:06 host dnsmasq[538]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jan 25 11:44:08 host dnsmasq[703]: started, version 2.72 cachesize 150
Jan 25 11:44:08 host dnsmasq[703]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect
Jan 25 11:44:08 host dnsmasq-dhcp[703]: DHCP, IP range 10.0.0.10 -- 10.0.0.111, lease time 12h
Jan 25 11:44:08 host dnsmasq-dhcp[703]: DHCP, sockets bound exclusively to interface eth0
Jan 25 11:44:08 host dnsmasq-tftp[703]: TFTP root is /cloud/tftpboot
Jan 25 11:44:08 host dnsmasq[703]: no servers found in /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf, will retry
Jan 25 11:44:08 host dnsmasq[703]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
Jan 25 11:44:09 host systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jan 25 11:44:15 host dnsmasq[703]: reading /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
Jan 25 11:44:15 host dnsmasq[703]: using nameserver 192.168.178.1#53
```

The pi was restarted at 11:44, so I didn't include much from before that.

**UPDATE:**
I realized the DHCPDISCOVER-packets are sent by dnsmasq itself and the PXE-pi rarely (every few hours) sends a DHCPDISCOVER itself. dnsmasq answers that request, but then there's no follow-up from the pxe-pi. Here's what wireshark says about the dnsmasq-response:

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    308 19222.402889 10.0.0.1              10.0.0.10             DHCP     389    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x26f30339

Frame 308: 389 bytes on wire (3112 bits), 389 bytes captured (3112 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Raspberr_XX:XX:XX (b8:27:eb:XX:XX:XX), Dst: Raspberr_XX:XX:XX (b8:27:eb:XX:XX:XX)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1), Dst: 10.0.0.10 (10.0.0.10)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
    Source Port: 67 (67)
    Destination Port: 68 (68)
    Length: 355
    Checksum: 0x157f [validation disabled]
    [Stream index: 1]
Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
    Message type: Boot Reply (2)
    Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
    Hardware address length: 6
    Hops: 0
    Transaction ID: 0x26f30339
    Seconds elapsed: 0
    Bootp flags: 0x0000 (Unicast)
    Client IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Your (client) IP address: 10.0.0.10 (10.0.0.10)
    Next server IP address: 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)
    Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
    Client MAC address: Raspberr_XX:XX:XX (b8:27:eb:XX:XX:XX)
    Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
    Server host name not given
    Boot file name not given
    Magic cookie: DHCP
    Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (Offer)
        Length: 1
        DHCP: Offer (2)
    Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
        Length: 4
        DHCP Server Identifier: 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)
    Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
        Length: 4
        IP Address Lease Time: (43200s) 12 hours
    Option: (58) Renewal Time Value
        Length: 4
        Renewal Time Value: (21600s) 6 hours
    Option: (59) Rebinding Time Value
        Length: 4
        Rebinding Time Value: (37800s) 10 hours, 30 minutes
    Option: (1) Subnet Mask
        Length: 4
        Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (255.255.255.0)
    Option: (28) Broadcast Address
        Length: 4
        Broadcast Address: 10.0.0.255 (10.0.0.255)
    Option: (60) Vendor class identifier
        Length: 9
        Vendor class identifier: PXEClient
    Option: (97) UUID/GUID-based Client Identifier
        Length: 17
        Client Identifier (UUID): 44444444-4444-4444-4444-444444444444
    Option: (43) Vendor-Specific Information (PXEClient)
        Length: 35
        Option 43 Suboption: (6) PXE discovery control
            Length: 1
            discovery control: 0x03
        Option 43 Suboption: (10) PXE menu prompt
            Length: 4
            menu prompt: 00505845
        Option 43 Suboption: (9) PXE boot menu
            Length: 23
            boot menu: 00001452617370626572727920506920426f6f74202020
        PXE Client End: 255
    Option: (255) End
        Option End: 255
```

The option "PXE Boot menu" is hex for "Raspberry Pi Boot   " (three spaces), after found several sources saying I had to use this name. But I also used "Raspberry Pi Boot" too before, no results.

Comment: `dhcp-authoritative` - try adding this, it'll let Dnsmasq know its the only server on the subnet.

Comment: @tobyd I added `dhcp-authoritative` to the config file, restarted dnsmasq, rebooted the pi. Still, tshark shows me the same, no answer to the dhcp-discover-packet

Comment: Logs from dnsmasq would sure help.

Comment: @Janka I added what dnsmasq logs into syslog. If there are other logfiles let me know.